# Orbits of irreducible binary forms over GF(p)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials

I am reading this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07418.pdf

I know the number of orbits for any $p$, when $n = 2$, is supposed to be $1$. But I wanted to compute it, using the formula at the bottom of page $4$.

Then I tried doing the case when $p = 2$, and when $p$ is odd.

For $p = 2$, I get $\frac{1}{|G|} = \frac{1}{(2)(3)} = \frac{1}{6}$

Next I get $a = 2, b = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}), c = 0, d = 0$, so since $a + b + c + d \neq 6$. I know I'm doing something wrong, but not sure where.

For $p$ is odd, I get $\frac{1}{|G|} = \frac{1}{(p^2 - p)(p^2  - 1)} $.

Next I get $a = (p -1)(p^2 - p), b = 0, c = \frac{1}{4} (p - 1)^2(p^2 + p), d = \frac{1}{4}(p-1)(p^2 - p)(p+1)$.

So $a + b + c + d = a + c + d = (p^2 - p)[(p- 1) + \frac{1}{4}(p - 1)(p +1) + \frac{1}{4}(p - 1)(p +1)]$
$=  (p^2 - p)(p - 1)[1 + \frac{1}{2}(p +1)]$. Again not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: At the bottom of p.3 $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)p^{n/d}$ is wrong, the number of irreducible homogeneous polynomials in two variables of degree $n$ up to a multiplicative constant is the same as the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ which is $\frac1n \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)p^{n/d}$.

Comment: @renus, This only changes what $a$ equals. Using that, I get when $p = n =2$ I have $a = 1$. But $a + b + c + d \neq 6$